# C++ pointers passing values into a function and ignoring cin operations

Tags: c++, function, pointers, cin

I was experimenting with pointers and created this example and I don't understand why this doesn't work. Could someone explain why the function does not perform the cin operations when I pass the values without referencing?

```
#included proper headers and stuff
...
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    swap(a,b);

    cout << "A: " << a << endl;
    cout << "B: " << b << endl;
    return 0;
}

void swap(int * p1, int *p2)
{
    cin >> *p1;
    cin >> *p2;
    int temp = *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 = temp;
}
```

Result 
cin is skipped
A: 0
B: 0

Comment: Didn't your compiler warn you here?

Comment: I'm curious which compiler this compiles on: I get `error C2664: 'swap' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'int *'`

Comment: Mine too gives error , i use Bloodshed - Dev C++

Comment: g++ 4.0.1 compiles it without a peep!

Comment: nope my compiler didnt give me any errors but i think thats because i somehow got lucky (or unlucky..) and ive got g++ 4.0.1 too!

Comment: The behavior of your program depends upon what you think the "proper headers and stuff" is. Each of the people who answered probably has filled in the beginning of your program differently. In future, *please* provide a **complete**, short sample program. See http://sscce.org/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh. You're passing integers where pointers are expected. The `swap()` function is using the (random garbage) values in those uninitialized integers as machine addresses, and is writing data to those addresses. This doesn't change the value in the integers you pass, of course -- it changes some other random place in memory. Often this kind of program will crash with a segmentation violation; you're just lucky (or unlucky).

It would work if you passed pointers to the integers -- i.e., `swap(&a, &b)` -- but I think you understand that case already.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the address of the variables, not the variables themselves.

```
int a, b;
swap(&a,&b);
```

Note the ampersands

Answer (score 0):

It should be actually `swap(&a,&b)` . Always have a reference for the pointers , your pointers p1 and p2 do not actually refer to any valid location.

Answer (score 0):

The part of your program that you skipped probably has this line:

```
using namespace std;
```

It also might have this line, which will be required:

```
extern void swap(int * p1, int *p2);
```

The `using` declaration brings **all** of the symbols from `std` into scope. Specifically, it brings in `std::swap`. The `swap` line in your `main` invokes `std::swap(int&, int&)` instead of what you intended.

This error is compounded by the fact that you are calling your own swap incorrectly. If want to invoke your swap, you must a) declare it before using it, and b) invoke it correctly.

Try this program:

```
#include <iostream>
extern void swap(int*, int*);

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    swap(&a,&b);

    std::cout << "A: " << a << "\n";
    std::cout << "B: " << b << "\n";
    return 0;
}

void swap(int * p1, int *p2)
{
    std::cin >> *p1;
    std::cin >> *p2;
    int temp = *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 = temp;
}
```